# Proving the equivalence of open and closed subset conditions for functions on metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I encountered a problem on this site that used the condition "For all closed sets $F$, $f^\mathrm{-1}(F)$ is closed" as a known identity to prove something else.

Further investigation tells me that for metric spaces, there are several subset conditions that hold true:

Say that $(M_1, d_1)$ and $(M_2, d_2)$ are metric spaces and that a function $f$ from $M_1$ to $M_2$ exists.

(1) For all open $G \subset M_2$, $f^\mathrm{-1}(G)$ is open.

(2) For all closed $F \subset M_2$, $f^\mathrm{-1}(F)$ is closed.

Are the above conditions - (1) and (2) - equivalent? If so, how would one prove that?

Comment: The preimage works nicely with some familiar operations like union and complement, for instance. You need to prove this second property, which is: $f^{-1}(A^c) = (f^{-1}(A))^c$, where $X^c$ denotes the complement of a set $X$. Work out through the definition and you'll see it follows easily.

Comment: @LiterallyanOrange the preimage is $(-1, 1)$,could you clarify what your example means?

Comment: I deleted it.  My brain was thinking image but I wrote preimage.